# Code Runner in VSCode is running in output instead of CMD in the Terminal

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I just re-installed my `VSCode` for some reason and after downloading the `Code Runner` extension, it is processing all the commands in the OUTPUT window instead of CMD in the Terminal...

I am compiling my `C++` code so I want that `cd` and `g++` command in my CMD window, and not in the output one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify to run in the integrated terminal per [their configuration setting](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner#configuration) by putting the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true
```

The setting is defaulted to `false`.

Comment: How to run program from VSCode in **windows cmd** (not in internal vscode terminal)

Comment: @NitishPrajapati are you asking me or telling me? code runner doesn't provide an option to run in an external terminal

Comment: How not to open a new terminal tab, if an (integrated) terminal is already open?

Answer (score 5):

1] Go to  File -> Preferences -> Settings

2] search "code-runner:Run In Terminal"

3] Enable "Whether to run code in Integrated Terminal" option.

[image]