# Output is shown on Terminal instead of Output section in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

As you can see, there is no output shown in output section. But the output is shown in terminal tab. Can someone help me in getting the output in output tab instead of Terminal tab ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

that is because you used the code runner extension, am i right? It runs the code by using the command  prompt or terminal and run the code with the directory to your file. So if you use code runner extension, it will run the code in the terminal because it uses the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is indeed supposed to be run from the terminal because you used the code-runner extension. Even though you used another method like running the code from python, it will still be running from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in your settings.json file:

```json
"code-runner.runInTerminal" : true
```

Courtesy of [Code Runner in VSCode is running in output instead of CMD in the Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63148583/11107541) (the opposite question).