# Visual studio code is showing the output in the debug console and not in the terminal

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I wanted to code c++ using visual studio code so I downloaded the extensions: c/c++ and Code runner. When i tried to run and debug my code I come to find that the output is being shown in the debug console and not in the terminal.

I’ve already changed the configuration of the extension (Code Runner) so it runs on terminal and I’ve also enabled the option of saving the project before running but nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: weird. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63907537/output-is-shown-on-terminal-instead-of-output-section-vs-code