# Why does my C code run in terminal but not in VS Code using Code Runner?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

During a class we started learning C, all of the tasks that I was given I managed to do expect when the scanf tasks came, after I couldn't make it work, I copied the code from the professor and I still couldn't make it work.
I am using vs code, code runner extension and gcc on ubuntu linux.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
 {
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("Zbir je %d\n", a+b);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output, it does not stop untill I press the stop button:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TURRC.png)

Comment: Your code is fine.  Try to run it from a terminal. The problem is within the way the code is run by vscode.

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text! You can't copy'n'paste it to try it out. As a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @Jabberwocky It works from the terminal so yes the problem must be with vs code, but I would really like to keep using it and make it work.

Comment: I found the answer !
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68516851/17318989

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code looks fine. You might want to change a setting in vs-code to run code in an integrated terminal.
Go to File ->Preference -> Settings. Add the following code:

```json
{
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true
}
```

Comment: I am kind of new to VS Code so I dont quite understand what you are telling me, how do I add code do the settings tab?

Comment: I googled how to add that to the settings and found it, thank you very much !

Comment: If it worked kindly mark it as answered.

Comment: I just did, first post sorry !

Comment: Thanks! No problem

Answer (score 0):

I tried running it in my machine and it ran correctly.

I can tell from the picture that you are using vscode and running it with an extension. The problem must be there

[image]

Comment: Please don't use pictures of code! You can't copy'n'paste it to try it out. As a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: But the code is useless, its the same as the post. I did it to show him that I copy and pasted it without changing anything

Comment: I tried it out and the code works for me too using terminal and the gcc commands.
But in vs code it does not.

Comment: What extension are you using to compile in vscode?

Comment: I am using Code Runner, while trying to solve the problem I installed Microsofts C/C++ extension but it didnt change anything.

Comment: I found the answer!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68516851/17318989