# vsCode does not output the result to "output"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I downloaded the program and configured a couple of details. (I'm almost sure that they do not affect the operation of the program). I wrote a simple code to output text. Everything works in the terminal, but it doesn't show anything in Output. (Python)
[image]

I don’t know how to fix this and I hope you can help me

P.S. I cleared settings.json and now it writes this:
[image]

Comment: run `python3 new.py` in terminal will show you output in terminal

Comment: It's not supposed to. There is nothing to fix.

Comment: The "Output" tab shows you system about (vscode/plugins/...), not your code's output. You want the "Terminal" tab.

Comment: you can tell by the fact that the screenshot shows "python -u <file>" in the _output_ panel, the asker is using the Code Runner extension (see also https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/blob/master/package.json). This is a pretty common question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Code Runner in VSCode is running in output instead of CMD in the Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63148583/code-runner-in-vscode-is-running-in-output-instead-of-cmd-in-the-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

You can install Code-Runner extension.

Then Search for **Run In Terminal** in Settings. Uncheck it can make codes output in OUTPUT section.

[image]

Then you can run codes by using **Run Code** button or shortcuts "Ctrl + Alt + N".

[image]